# The meaning of the "value" attribute of radio buttons

Tags: html, radio-button

What is the real purpose of the `value` attribute of radio buttons?

(Yes, I have read the related articles on w3schools and MDN, but it is still unclear.)

In other words, which set of values should be assigned to the `value` attributes in the example below:

- `Red`, `Yellow`, `Green`, `Red`, `Yellow`, `Green` **or**
- `color1`, `color2`, `color3`, `color4`, `color5`, `color6` **or**
- `red1`, `yellow1`, `green1`, `red2`, `yellow2`, `green2`**?**

```html
<article>
  <h1>Saturday</h1>

  <p>Which color you prefer on Saturdays?</p>

  <input type="radio" name="saturday-color" id="color1" value="?">
  <label for="color1">Red</label>

  <input type="radio" name="saturday-color" id="color2" value="?">
  <label for="color2">Yellow</label>

  <input type="radio" name="saturday-color" id="color3" value="?">
  <label for="color3">Green</label>
</article>

<article>
  <h1>Sunday</h1>

  <p>Which color you prefer on Sundays?</p>

  <input type="radio" name="sunday-color" id="color4" value="?">
  <label for="color4">Red</label>

  <input type="radio" name="sunday-color" id="color5" value="?">
  <label for="color5">Yellow</label>

  <input type="radio" name="sunday-color" id="color6" value="?">
  <label for="color6">Green</label>
</article>
```

Comment: You probably should be using fieldset/legend instead of article/h1+p

Comment: well you are selecting something, you need to know what you selected when you submit the form. What is the value you use. It is whatever you need it to be.

Comment: It's whatever you need it to be. We can't give you the answer. You're read the docs, so what's unclear about the value attribute?

Comment: @j08691 Well, I cannot say that it is **completely** unclear, but since I never worked with HTML/JS that interacts with a server (all my coding is around userscripts and similar things), **I'm not sure** whether a value should be unique (like in the 2nd and 3rd example sets) or not (like in the 1st example set).

Comment: It would be valid HTML to repeat the value in a set, but programatically it wouldn't make much sense. In a radio button group you're asking the user to select zero or one options from a group. That's it. You could have five radio buttons, all with the same value but it would be mostly pointless. It really comes down to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value as the name suggests is the actual value of the radio button which means that when you add javascript and with on change events you would be able to access the value using event.target.value. And you would then handle it accordingly. You would understand the bigger picture once you start manipulating it with javascript.

Also when inside the `<form></form>` tags the selected radio button's value attribute would be the one that would be sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Given a collection of radio buttons with the name `foo` and different values: When the form is submitted, the form data will include `foo=the-value-of-the-checked-radio-button`.

Use whatever value is useful for you to recieve on the server.

Comment: For example, [here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/what-is-the-value-attribute-doing-for-the-radio-buttons) it it stated that "The value property on a radio button is used server-side to determine which button was selected. It's important to set different values for radio buttons **in the same group** for server-side implementation". Notice the bold part, this is actually what my question is about. If I assign `Red` as the value of the 1st button in the 1st group and also in the 2nd group, is that correct? Is it correct to assign the same values when they are assigned in different groups?

Comment: You can differentiate between `name-of-group-1=red` and `name-of-group-2=red`